# Выбор лицензии на opensource продукт, использующий иные opensource компоненты

Tags: лицензирование, opensource

Выбираем лицензию на opensource. Внутри используется много opensource-компонентов. Мы готовы выбрать любую максимально либеральную лицензию. Вопрос в следующем: ограничивают ли используемые компоненты выбор лицензии на использующий их продукт в сторону увеличения свободы использования?

Comment: это зависит от лицензии. некоторые лицензии требуют, что бы весь продукт был покрыт определенной лицензией.

Answer (score 1):

"Вопрос в следующем: ограничивают ли используемые компоненты выбор лицензии на использующий их продукт в сторону увеличения свободы использования?"

Да, ограничивают. Если, например, в проекте используется компоненты под GNU GPL v2+ или GNU AGPL, то, согласно их требованиям, весь проект должен быть также под этими лицензиями и выпустить его под какой-нибудь "максимально либеральной" лицензией, например MIT, уже не получится.